# How to add N to every value of a Counter? - python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, counter

**Is there any equivalent to numpy `ufunc` for a Counter object?**

For example to add N to all values in counter, I have to do this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'])
>>> n = 2
>>> y = Counter({k:v+n for k,v in x.items()})
>>> x
Counter({'foo': 2, 'bar': 2})
>>> y
Counter({'foo': 4, 'bar': 4})
```

Given 1 trillion key, it will surely take much longer than using `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'])
>>> k, v = zip(*x.items())
>>> n = 2
>>> _v = np.array(v) + n
>>> y = Counter(dict(zip(k, list(_v))))
>>> y
Counter({'foo': 4, 'bar': 4})
```

**Is there any other way to achieve the same +N for all values in a Counter?**

Comment: Use a simple loop and update the values in same Counter dict, creating another `Counter` or simple `dict` will result in another intermediate dictionary with 1 trillion keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a new Counter with the same keys and only the increment then sum that with the original:

```
increment = Counter(dict.fromkeys(x, n))
y = x + increment
```

Not that `Counter` objects are suited for trillions of keys; if your datasets are that large consider using different tools, like a database for example.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'])
>>> n = 2
>>> x + Counter(dict.fromkeys(x, n))
Counter({'foo': 4, 'bar': 4})
>>> y = Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'spam'])
>>> y + Counter(dict.fromkeys(y, n))
Counter({'foo': 4, 'bar': 4, 'spam': 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with default value of `+N` instead?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = defaultdict(lambda: 2)  # +N = +2
>>> for key in ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']:
...     x[key] += 1
...
>>> x
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000000002A4D128>, {'foo': 4, 'bar': 4})
```